# Why does std::constructible_from require destructible?

Tags: c++

I've been looking into the std::constructible_from concept in C++ and noticed that its definition includes both destructible and is_constructible_v:

```cpp
template<class _Tp, class... _Args>
concept constructible_from =
    destructible<_Tp> && is_constructible_v<_Tp, _Args...>;
```

I understand why is_constructible_v is necessary, but I'm unclear as to why destructible is also required.

Comment: `constructible_from<T, Args...>` is meant to be true if one can write `T t{args...}` (with `args...` of suitable types). But that won't in fact compile if `T` doesn't have an accessible destructor.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik That's already part of `is_constructible_v` though and `std::destructible` is stronger: It requires the type to be noexcept-destructible. It was generally always UB to have a destructor of a user-provided type to a standard library function throw, but I guess they just wanted to make this a bit stronger with concepts by straight-up requiring noexcept.